# keep records increment jpa-sqlite sqlite

Tags: sqlite, eclipselink

My problem is when I save a person domiciled the id of the person record is 1 and the address 2 and when I save another record the id of person is 3 and the domicile 4 and so is increased, I want to increase as it should be is to record who is 1 and for of registered prox 1 for registration is 2 and 2 the next 3 and 3 and so on.

Then I leave the source code of the entities, the main, the method to keep and what gives me the console when I create the tables. I'm using netbeans 7.4 and EclipseLink library jpa2.1 and jdbc for sqlite dirver

```java
@Entity
public class Persona implements Serializable {
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nombre;
    @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Domicilio domicilio;     

    public Persona() {

    }

    public Persona(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        domicilio= new Domicilio();
    }

    public Domicilio getDomicilio() {
        return domicilio;
    }

    public void setDomicilio(Domicilio domicilio) {
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Entity Domicilio:

```java
@Entity
public class Domicilio implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String calle;

    public Domicilio() {
    }

    public Domicilio(String calle) {
        this.calle = calle;
    }

    public String getCalle() {
        return calle;
    }

    public void setCalle(String calle) {
        this.calle = calle;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Method found in the class PersonaJpaController used to save the record

```java
public void guardar(){
    persona= new Persona("angel");
    persona.getDomicilio().setCalle("alpatacal");
    create(persona);
}
```

This is my main program

```java
public class Pruebaentidades {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public  static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pruebaentidadesPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();// create tables 

        PersonaJpaController p= new PersonaJpaController(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pruebaentidadesPU"));
        p.guardar();
    }
}
```

This is what gives me the console when I create tables

```
[EL Info]: 2014-01-03 17:27:01.189--ServerSession(24979675)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
[EL Info]: connection: 2014-01-03 17:27:01.379--Not able to detect platform for vendor name [SQLite3]. Defaulting to [org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DatabasePlatform]. The database dialect used may not match with the database you are using. Please explicitly provide a platform using property eclipselink.platform.class.name.
[EL Info]: connection: 2014-01-03 17:27:01.446--ServerSession(24979675)--file:/C:/Users/VM/Desktop/Mis Proyectos/Proyectos Netbeans/pruebaentidades/build/classes/_pruebaentidadesPU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2014-01-03 17:27:01.6--ServerSession(24979675)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error
Error Code: 0
Call: ALTER TABLE PERSONA ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSONA_DOMICILIO_ID FOREIGN KEY (DOMICILIO_ID) REFERENCES DOMICILIO (ID)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE PERSONA ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSONA_DOMICILIO_ID FOREIGN KEY (DOMICILIO_ID) REFERENCES DOMICILIO (ID)")
```

Comment: I think you may want to pay attention to “`Not able to detect platform for vendor name [SQLite3]. Defaulting to [org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DatabasePlatform]. The database dialect used may not match with the database you are using. Please explicitly provide a platform using property eclipselink.platform.class.name`” in that log trace…

Answer (score 0):

for those who have this same problem I want to say that the solution to the problem was to create a sequence for each table and use the strategy generation secuence.
add these statements for each entity allowing me to create a sequence for each table

Entity Persona:

@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PERS_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator ( name = "PERS_SEQ" , sequenceName = "PERS_SEQ")

Entity Domicilio:

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE , generator = "DOM_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator ( name = "DOM_SEQ" , sequenceName = "DOM_SEQ")